# pytorch - reciprocal of torch.gather

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, tensor, torch

Given an input tensor `x` and a tensor of indices `idxs`, I want to retrieve all elements of `x` whose index is not present in `idxs`. That is, taking the opposite of the [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) function output.

Example with `torch.gather`:

```
>>> x = torch.arange(30).reshape(3,10)
>>> idxs = torch.tensor([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]], dtype=torch.long)
>>> torch.gather(x, 1, idxs)
tensor([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [14, 15, 16],
        [27, 28, 29]])
```

What indeed I want to achieve is

```
tensor([[ 0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]])
```

What could it be an effective and efficient implementation, possibly employing *torch* utilities? I wouldn't like to use any for-loops.

I'm assuming `idxs` has only **unique** elements in its deepest dimension. For example `idxs` would be the result of calling `torch.topk`.

Comment: You have an inconsistency in your desired output. What happens if `idxs` has two identical elements on the same line, *e.g.* `[[1,1,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`. What would the result be in that case?

Comment: @Ivan I'm assuming *idxs* has only unique elements in its deepest dimension. Let's say *idxs* is the output of `torch.topk`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be looking to construct a tensor of shape `(x.size(0), x.size(1)-idxs.size(1))` (here `(3, 7)`). Which would correspond to the complementary indices of `idxs`, with regard to the shape of `x`, *i.e.*:

```
tensor([[0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

I propose to first build a tensor shaped like `x` that would reveal the positions we want to keep and those we want to discard, a sort of mask. This can be done using  [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.scatter.html). This essentially scatters `0`s at desired location, namely `m[i, idxs[i][j]] = 0`:

```
>>> m = torch.ones_like(x).scatter(1, idxs, 0)
tensor([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Then grab the non zeros (the complementary part of `idxs`). Select the 2nd indices on `axis=1`, and reshape according to the target tensor:

```
>>> idxs_ = m.nonzero()[:, 1].reshape(-1, x.size(1) - idxs.size(1))
tensor([[0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9],
        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

Now you know what to do, right? Same as for the `torch.gather` example you gave, but this time with `idxs_`:

```
>>> torch.gather(x, 1, idxs_)
tensor([[ 0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]])
```

---

In summary:

```
>>> idxs_ = torch.ones_like(x).scatter(1, idxs, 0) \
        .nonzero()[:, 1].reshape(-1, x.size(1) - idxs.size(1))

>>> torch.gather(x, 1, idxs_)
```

Comment: You can simplify the code using a boolean mask
```m = torch.ones_like(x, dtype=torch.bool).scatter(1, idxs, 0)``` to select values with
```x[m].reshape(-1, x.size(1) - idxs.size(1))```.

Comment: Indeed, that's a nicer - and more natural! - way of using the mask.